# C - convert number string to SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT

Tags: c

I need help converting a number string to a SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT value to use decimal and numeric database data types. The SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT value is a 16-byte hexadecimal unsigned integer. For example, I have a string "12312312899012312890522341231231232198", that contains 38 digits (maximum for SQL SERVER decimal or numeric data types). In other languages such a c# there is a built-in conversion function, but my Visual studio 2019 does not allow me to directly use 128-bit integers in the C++ environment. The Microsoft help page offers example with a small,2-byte integer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

```
bool ConvertToNumericStruct (char* s, SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT* v){
int sc = (int)strlen(s), scale = 0, i,y, z; 
char c, p = 0, d; bool minus = false;
int _tmp, x, carryover;
memset(v->val, 0, 16);
for (i = 0; i < sc; i++) {
    c = s[i];
    if (i == 0 && c == '-')minus = true;
    else if (c == '.') { if (scale == 0)scale = sc - i - 1; else return false; }
    else if (c < '0' || c>'9') return false;
    else
    {
        if (p > 38) return false;
        d = c - 48;
        _tmp = 0;
        carryover = d;
        y = 0; z = 0;
        for (x = sc - 1; x > -1; x--)
        {
            if (y % 2 == 1)
            {
                _tmp = (v->val[z] >> 4) * 10 + carryover;
                v->val[z] &= 0x0F;
                v->val[z] |= ((_tmp % 16) << 4 & 0xF0);
                z++;
                if (z > 15) break;
            }
            else {
                _tmp = (v->val[z] & 0x0F) * 10 + carryover;
                v->val[z] &= 0Xf0;
                v->val[z] |= ((_tmp % 16) & 0x0F);
            }
            y++;
            carryover = _tmp / 16;
        }
        p++;
    }
}

v->precision = p;
v->scale = scale;
if (minus) v->sign = 0; else v->sign = 1;
return true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data defined by decimal or numeric into database such as MySql via UnixODBC with the function SQLBindParameter,you can just use SQL_C_CHAR for fCtype and SQL_CHAR for fSqltype with a char-string buffer.No need to convert.That would be done implicitly.